# Who is superior in term of religious status: elder brother`s wife or paternal uncle`s wife?

Tags: practice

Need explanation with quotes from shastra

Comment: "Eider"- did u mean elder or either?

Comment: I think its elder. I and L are close enough in a keyboard. @YDS